# Automatically repeat first column when grid layout wraps with CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to construct a layout that conceptually is like this:

```
h1| A1 | B1 | C1...
h2| A2 | B2 | C2...
h3| A3 | B3 | C3...
```

where `h1` is a header describing the content at A1, B1, C1.

When there are too many columns, I'd like it wrap like this:

```
h1| A1 | B1 | C1...
h2| A2 | B2 | C2...
h3| A3 | B3 | C3...
h1| E1...
h2| E2...
h3| E3...
```

I'm currently using flexbox but intending to switch to grid.

The thing currently looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in CSS? Or will I need to use JavaScript to track the width and repeat the header as necessary?

Comment: No, Css-grid can't do that dynamically and it can't create elements to make your new headings. They would have to be in the HTML already.